# Cannot upload my GPG keys to any key server - "Server indicated a failure"

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

I have extended the expiry date of my GPG keys, and now I want the network to synchronise them. So I'm trying

```
$ gpg --send-keys 0578BBA15F19661D18F7C3457437FCBA03E4CB85
gpg: sending key 7437FCBA03E4CB85 to hkp://keys.gnupg.net
gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure
gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure

$ gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --send-keys 0578BBA15F19661D18F7C3457437FCBA03E4CB85
gpg: sending key 7437FCBA03E4CB85 to hkp://pgp.mit.edu
gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure
gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure
```

etc. I am on Debian Stretch. I also tried to do it via Enigmail, which just responds with

```
Sending of keys failed
gpg: sending key 7437FCBA03E4CB85 to hkp://pgp.surfnet.nl
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with gpg version 2.1.18 I had been using (Debian 
Stretch). Updating to 2.2.12 made it possible to upload the keys again.